# Uniswap V3 Path

Tags: uniswap

With Uniswap V2 specifying the path for router function was quite simple:

```
address[] path;
path[0] = address1;
path[1] = address2;
path[2] = address3;
```

However, with Unswap V3, path is no more of type address[].  It's of type byte.  I've looked through their documentation but don't understand what the byte variable should consist of and how to do the conversion.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a path in such a form:

(token_in, pool_fee, token_out)

And you can expand it further where `token_out` should be the next `token_in`:

(token_0, pool_fee_0, token_1, pool_fee_1, token_2)

and then you encode an array with [abi.encodePacked(...)](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode)

```
// You want to swap USDC into WETH and then WETH to UNI
address USDC = address(...);
address WETH = address(...);
address UNI  = address(...);

uint24 USDC_WETH_POOL_FEE = ...;
uint24 WETH_UNI_POOL_FEE  = ...;

bytes swapPath = abi.encodePacked(
   USDC, USDC_WETH_POOL_FEE, WETH, WETH_UNI_POOL_FEE, UNI
);

// Perform a swap
amountOut = ISwapRouter(ROUTER).exactInput(
    path: swapPath,
    ...
);
```