# Uniswap v3: How do I get the path bytes from solidity from array function parameters?

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap, bytes, uniswapv3

I am trying to write a smart contract that can facilitate multihop swaps. It is important that I am able to pass in 2 arrays into the swap function: an address[] of the tokens and uint256[] of the pool fees (though they could be 16 bit unsigned/signed ints or whatever it doesn't matter, its just a rough idea as long as they can support the values needed for the pool fees).
I have made the assertion that the length of the pool fees is exactly 1 less than the length of the token addresses.

I have looked at [Uniswap V3 Path](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109215/uniswap-v3-path) and the Uniswap documentation and have come up with this code so far:

```
function concatPathParams(bytes[] calldata addresses, bytes[] calldata poolFees) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
    assert(addresses.length == (poolFees.length - 1));

    bytes memory output;

    uint lastIdx = addresses.length - 1;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        output = abi.encodePacked(output, addresses[i]);

        if (i != lastIdx) {
            output = abi.encodePacked(output, poolFees[i]);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
function v3MultihopExactInput(uint256 amountIn, bytes[] calldata addresses, bytes[] calldata poolFees) external returns (uint256 amountOut) {
    TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(address(uint160(bytes20(addresses[0]))), msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
    TransferHelper.safeApprove(address(uint160(bytes20(addresses[0]))), address(swapRouter), amountIn);

    bytes memory path = concatPathParams(bytes[](addresses), poolFees);

    ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams memory params =
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams({
            path: path,
            recipient: msg.sender,
            deadline: block.timestamp,
            amountIn: amountIn,
            amountOutMinimum: 0
        });

    amountOut = swapRouter.exactInput(params);
}
```

The TransferHelper is coming from Uniswap's transfer helper.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. If someone can point me to the appropriate documentation then that would be beyond helpful. I've tried to decode a uniswap swap to see if my issue isn't actually with the path however I have been unsuccesful.

Helpful info:

The concatPathParams with the inputs ["0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2", "0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984"] (WETH, UNI) and ["0x01F4"] (pool fee of 500) returns 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc201f41f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984 which to my eye looks correct.

I then approve the Uniswap V3 contract (0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45) and set it up with the params:

[image]

(path: 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc201f41f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984, recipient: (my address), amount in: 1000000000000 (how much the contract is approved for and my balance or less of WETH), amountOutMinimum: 0)

The amount out minimum is set to 0 for testing purposes because I don't care about being frontrun with that little ether. The transaction will fail if I confirm it.

Can someone offer their advice here? Thanks!